# css not applied to jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to load the contents dynamically from a json file. Problem is that CSS will not be applied to this content. Here is my code:

```
<div id="main"> 
    <div id="produkter_menu">
    <ul id="listContent">
    </ul>
    </div>

<script>
 $.getJSON('js/products.json', function(data) {

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for(index in data) {
            var content1 = new Array (Object.keys(data[index])[i]);
        }
        $("#listContent").append("<li>" + content1[0] + "</li>");
    }
    }

    );
</script>
```

CSS code:

```
.produkter_menu ul {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
width:50%;
list-style-type: none;
}

.produkter_menu ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000; 
padding: 25px 11px;
background-color: #fff;
display:block;
border: 1px solid #cacaca;
height: 30px;
}

.produkter_menu ul li a:visited {
color: #000; 
 }
```

The browser just displays the list items.

One more question: Is it always good to dynamically read the contents from a json file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try using the wrap content $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: Your style is for `li a`, but you put content in `li`.

Comment: You are using IDs but class selectors, e.g, should be: `#produkter_menu ul`

Answer (score 1):

Html tags are using "id" instead "class" atributes, simple change your css selectors
Example:`.produkter_menu ul` to  `#produkter_menu ul`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks. yes that was helpful as commented by @A. Wolff

Answer (score 0):

Use `#produkter_menu` instead of `.produkter_menu` because you tried to select a non existent class

The CSS `#` is used to select `id` attributes in HTML

while

The CSS `.` is used to select `class` attributes in HTML

Here is a revised example of your code

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
#produkter_menu ul {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
width:50%;
list-style-type: none;
}

#produkter_menu ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000; 
padding: 25px 11px;
background-color: #fff;
display:block;
border: 1px solid #cacaca;
height: 30px;
}

#produkter_menu ul li a:visited {
color: #000; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your CSS is using class selectors, but you never assign that class to your list elements.  Try changing your CSS to these selectors:

```
#listContent ul
#listContent ul li a
#listContent ul li a:visited
```

Second, unless your content array actually includes 'a' tag markup, it isn't being referenced by your CSS, because your CSS points to 'a' child elements of 'li' elements of 'ul' elements that belong to the #listContent element.  So you either need to change the CSS selector to:

```
    #listContent ul li
```

Or you need to change your javascript like so:

```
    $("#listContent").append("<li><a>" + content1[0] + "</a></li>");
```

If your content array DOES contain 'a' tag markup, you can ignore the second part of my answer, but you still need to correct the CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

For your CSS question, you should check on google "CSS selectors" to understand the difference between an ID and a class (hint : you should replace your '.' by '#' and it should work.

For the other question : Is it always good to dynamically read the contents from a json file?
Not always!

The problem you might have will be related to security. Who do you want to allow to access the data contained in the file?
Using a server side language to send those data would secure it (asp, php,...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. about dynamically reading the son content: Security is not an issue. Because Cross domain access is not allowed. Right now I have data supplied in a json file. I have two options. 1. Get the data manually and put it between in html tags. 2. Append the data dynamically with jquery Which one should I go with?